# CSS * {margin: 0;padding: 0;} override

Tags: css, margin

Hey all, i am in need of some help with figuring out how to override the "* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}" in my css.

The reason why is that i have this css:

```
 .postcomments { width: 547px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; margin: 0 0 5px 0;} 
 .postcomments a { text-decoration: underline;}
 .postcomments ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;}
 .postcomments ul li { width: 547px; margin: 0 0 5px 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;}
 .postcomments .right { color: #474747; font-size: 11px; background: #fff url('http://www.nextbowluser.com/img/ucBG.gif') no-repeat top left; line-height: 17px; padding: 5px 0 0 0; width: 430px; position: relative; float: right; min-height: 50px;}
 .postcomments .right .bottom { padding: 0 5px 15px 5px; background: #fff url('http://www.nextbowluser.com/img/ucBG.gif') no-repeat bottom right; min-height: 50px;}
 .postcomments .arrow { left: -15px; top: 20px; position: absolute;}
 .avatar { border: none !important;}

 .postcomments .left {float: left; margin: 0 7px 0 0;}
 .postcomments .gravatar { background: #fff; width: 80px; height: 60px; margin: 0 0px 0 0; padding: 3px;}
 .postcomments .name { font-size: 11px; margin: 2px 0 0 0; color: #000;}
 .avatar { border: none !important;}
```

and it displays just fine WITHOUT the * {margin: 0;padding: 0;}:

```
 1st comment
 2nd comment
 3rd comment
```

However, when i add that to the CSS, it makes the comments stack wrong:

```
 1st comment
    2nd comment
        3rd comment
```

I would just take out the * {margin: 0;padding: 0;} but some other things on the page needs that in order for that to be displayed correctly. So my question is, how can i override the  {margin: 0;padding: 0;} for just that postcomments part of the page?

Thanks! :o)

David

**UPDATE:** 
Well. still can not get it correctly. After taking out the margin: 0px for the whole site- it makes the site look terrible. And if i have to add margin: 0px to every element to the page to make it look like it would with the * then thats not good. I still just need something to bypass it for the .postcomments part and thats it.

Comment: Just don't do it. Give all block elements your own margin/padding.

Comment: What's your HTML structure like? It seems strange that the comments are being indented either way.

Comment: Balus C is right; don't do that. However, my instincts tell me there are anchor elements (`<a>`) for which you haven't changed the margin padding. You also should ditch the use of `!important` and look into CSS Specificity - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try it with !important?

```
.postcomments {
   margin: 15px  !important;
   padding: 15px !important;
}
```

i am using 15px, but you can use whatever value works for you

Comment: Don't use `!important` - instead learn about CSS specificity - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen !important works for my case. Why is it not adviised ? What can be the issues ? I am building my app on bunch of css's and its hard to find where to hit and !important solved the problem in a second.

Comment: My comment got too long so I asked and answered a question: [Why is the use of `!important` discouraged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582385/why-is-the-use-of-important-discouraged/15582386)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use one reset.css ([eric meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) e.g.) scripts available. then watch how you build the unordered lists. if there are nested ul you would normally get a margin-left for each ul

Answer (score 0):

.postcomments should override *, since a class is more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Matt. but it does not seem to be so. The * {margin: 0;padding: 0;) is placed before the .postcomments css and it still does that. I even added it after the .postcomments and still ends up the same.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide more specificity then what the other answers contain

try putting the tag infront of the class, or a parent tag

```
div.postcomments {
span.postcomments {
```

or if that's not an option, you can always resort to

```
* .postcomments {
```