# important property for two screen resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

Supppose I have following code :

```
    <ul>
        <li>Menu1
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="firstmenu">submenu-1</li>
                <li>submenu-2</li>
                <li>submenu-3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu2
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="firstmenu" id="first">submenu-1</li>
                <li>submenu-2</li>
                <li>submenu-3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here, I have give padding-left to sub-menu's `li` first item with following code:

```
   .submenu li:first-child{padding-left: 173px;}
```

But for **Menu2** 's first `li`, I want different padding.So for that I have used its ID like that :

```
#first{padding-left:500px !important;}
```

So basically, I have overridden the previous left with `!important`.

Now I want to make it responsive, so for that I am using :

```
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 768px)
    and (max-width : 894px) {
        #first{padding-left:150px !important;}
    }
```

But as I have already given `!important` to `@media all`, it is not considering `@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 894px)`.

So basically I want to use different **padding** for screen resolution 768 to 894.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

The `!important` anotation has the highest priority on the [CSS priority scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_Priority_scheme_.28highest_to_lowest.29). This case is a good example of [why is the use of !important discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582385/why-is-the-use-of-important-discouraged).

The solution is to remove the need of `!important`. It could be accomplished in many ways, as the one presented below:

```css
.submenu li.firstmenu{
    padding-left: 173px;
}

.submenu li.firstmenu#first{
    padding-left:500px
}

@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 894px) {
    .submenu li.firstmenu#first{
       padding-left:150px;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

The selectors above are essentially the same as yours, but use the `firstmenu` class as it's seen on your HTML layout instead the pseudo-selector `:first-child`. `.submenu li.firstmenu` **states** *select a `li` element whose class is "firstmenu" and is descendant of any element whose class is "submenu"*, while `.submenu li:first-child` **states** *select a `li` element, first child of its parent and descendant of any element whose class is "submenu"*.

To refine the padding as requested, the `id` of the target element is used. `submenu li.firstmenu#first` **states** *select a li element with ID equal to "myid", whose class is "firstmenu" and which is descendant of any element whose class is "submenu"*. The same result could be accomplished for this HTML layout using only the id selector (`#firstmenu`), as seen on other answers.

Comment: Thanks for your time ... Its working for me ..
Just want to know the reason behind its working .. Can you please explain above code ?

Comment: Added explanation if you need more or have some doubt you can ask. Happy to help :)

Comment: @4dgaurav I were improving the answer from the review queue while your edit was done. My apologizes.

Comment: @laconbass I appreciate your time and efforts for the the edit. Its very well explained Thank you so much...:)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need `!important` actually, because ID selectors have a higher level of priority than classe/element selectors (unless dozens of classes or hundreds of elements in a single selector). Remove `!important` and you'll still get what you want.

```css
.submenu li:first-child {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

#first {
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Menu1
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="firstmenu">submenu-1</li>
      <li>submenu-2</li>
      <li>submenu-3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu2
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="firstmenu" id="first">submenu-1</li>
      <li>submenu-2</li>
      <li>submenu-3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

More details please read W3C spec on [**selectors' specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), there's a very intuitive table of comparing different selectors.

Comment: Thanks leo for your precious time ..But somehow I didn't manage to make it work as per your solution. It is working nice with @4dgaurav 's suggested solution. And thanks for link.

Comment: @Twix Just updated with a demo. What do you see in my demo? For me it's work on Chrome, Firefox and IE11. If it's not working for you could you tell me what browser you are using?

Comment: I am using chrome and fire fox .. I have lots of classes in li ..
Actually I am using wordpress and I have just provided replica code excluding classes and other menu items ..

Comment: If that's the case, it might be unreliable and you'd better use @4dgaurav solution. However I guess you may also take some time on optimizing your HTML and CSS, because I'm afraid super long selectors (which could even override ID selectors) are hardly maintainable.