# Is there possible that remove !important property from element on specific resolution?

Tags: css

I'm using carousel slider more than two times and its `.item` height is `100%`. I had to adjust the main slider on specific height, so i added a class `.custom-slider` in `header` tag put the style with `!important` tag, because there was already `100%` height .

```
.custom-slider {
    height: 645px !important;
}
```

Its adjusted and working fine. Now I have to adjust the on different resolution, so i have to reduce the height `645px` to `496px`, but due to `!important` property new added height does not working.

I'm trying following style on 1024 reslution, but its not working.

```
.custom-slider {
    height: 496px !important;
}
```

This accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437130/important-property-for-two-screen-resolution) is well explained, but i didn't resolve my issue, can any guide me regarding this. I would like to appreciate.

Comment: Why do you need the !important in the first place?

Comment: This seems like the same question as the one you've linked to.  Can you explain why you need a new question / what the difference is?  Also - there should be no need to use !important if it's your own code.

Comment: because there was already  `height : 100%` on `header` tag, and i'm using more than two times on same page so i can't remove the `height : 100%`.

Comment: use `max-height: 496px;`

Comment: See this answer to understand CSS better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902858/order-of-prioritization-when-using-multiple-contradictory-css-files/5902873#5902873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style to `max-height` and remove the `important!`

```
.custom-slider {
    max-height: 645px;
}
```

You could also make the selector more specific by adding the tag or a parents id/class. This would give the style a higher priority.

```
body div.custom-slider {
    max-height: 645px;
}
```

Comment: A nice trick to add specificity for the sake of adding specificity without any drawback is to repeat the class: `.custom-slider.custom-slider {}`. It matches exactly the same thing and once you know the trick, you instantly know why the previous gal/guy wrote it like that ^^ (edit: [it's in a spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572081/css-class-repetition-to-increase-specificity#11581106))

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to do this within the same resolution ( without using media queries ) you should be able to add a second class and give that a defined height as well - it should overwrite the first one. For example:

```
<div class="custom-slider secondary-height"></div>

.custom-slider.secondary-height {
  height: 496px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGmrwZ

when you define a media query, it will catach the relevant one.
if you go from bottom up, only the relevant !important will catch. 
and since they have same "cascading juice" the winner will be:
the one that have the appropriate media  trageting and the one that comes last, so combining them will solve the issue.

scss example

```
  .custom-slider{ 
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
   @media (min-width:700px) {
    height: 20px !important;
       border:1px solid green;
  }
  @media (min-width:900px) {
    height: 80px !important;
    border:1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

by the way, if your css is loaded after the slider's css, you do not need !important.

same goes if you add a parent container to your css.