# How to override bootstrap table td style?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3
I have a HTML code as follows:

```
<div data-name="md-PersianDateTimePicker">
    <table class="table table-striped">        
        <tr>
            <td data-name="day">03</td>
            <td data-name="day">04</td>
            <td data-name="day">05</td>
            <td data-name="day">06</td>
            <td data-name="day">07</td>
            <td data-name="day">09</td>
            <td data-name="day" class="text-danger">09</td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I set `padding:2px` to each `td`?

I tested the following, it doesn't work!

```
[data-name="md-PersianDateTimePicker"] td{ 
   padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: it's should work, show : http://jsfiddle.net/6fu2rr60/

Comment: Which browser are you using to test this?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome 28

Comment: put an important! after the value

Comment: @vals: that's  what  i answered :)

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath you are rigth, but the time difference is only one minute, I couldn't see your answer !

Comment: @vals : i was telling you to upvote my answer if it is correct :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply increase the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) of your selector. If what you have currently doesn't work, try adding the table into it as well:

```css
[data-name="md-PersianDateTimePicker"] table.table.table-striped td[data-name="day"] {
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanna `[data-name="md-PersianDateTimePicker"] td` instead?

Comment: @Mohammad This does select the `td` elements as those have the `[data-name]` attribute.

Comment: Why include the table here. If I am less specific (e.g. all tds), it should also work?

Answer (score 1):

add `!important` specifier

```
[data-name="md-PersianDateTimePicker"] td{ 
   padding: 2px !important;
}
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/drsydn4u/)

**NOTE** :

> Never use !important on site-wide css. Only use !important on
>   page-specific css that overrides site-wide or foreign css

Comment: `!important` is almost always unnecessary and is usually regarded as bad practice. All `!important` does is offer a hacky way of increasing specificity, but in turn it makes the CSS much harder to maintain.

Comment: Relevant, but bad. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15582385/1317805.

Comment: Wasn't me who down voted. Answers which recommend `!important` are often greeted with a negative response. As I mentioned before, there's simply no need to use it.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly : so you are telling that never use !important anywhere ?

Comment: I don't personally, no. If your CSS is well maintained there's really no reason to need to use it, ever.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly check my note