# Bootstratp-Table Too Big For Screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-table, bulma

Note I am using the http://bootstrap-table.com library, specifically the Bulma version.

See below for visual understanding, but here is the gist. I have a large table with lots of info, when the screen is not big enough, the table becomes scrollable. I want the table to shrink so it ALWAYS fits the screen size. Currently, I do have mobile cards, but I don't want that for my computer users of course. I have tried EVERY CSS and other solution online but it seems the bootstrap-table is overwriting it and I cannot get it to work. I checked their docs and Google info for that library to no avail. Any advice or help is VERY much appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/themes/bulma/bootstrap-table-bulma.min.css">

<div class="wrapper is-desktop is-mobile">
  <table data-show-columns-toggle-all="true" classes="table-sm" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="true" class="is-narrow table-responsive" data-toggle="table" data-search-highlight="true" data-advanced-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-id-table="advancedTable" data-mobile-responsive="true" data-sticky-header="true" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="false" searchable="false">Favorite</th>
      <th data-sortable="false" searchable="false">Image</th>
      <th data-field="CRN" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">CRN</th>
      <th data-field="Subject" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Subject</th>
      <th data-field="Course" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Course</th>
      <th data-field="Credits" data-sortable="true" searchable="true" >Credits</th>
      <th data-field="Title" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Title</th>
      <th data-field="Days" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Days</th>
      <th data-field="Times" data-sortable="true" searchable="true" >Times</th>
      <th data-field="Instructors" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Instructor</th>
      <th data-field="Attribute" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Attribute</th>
      <th data-field="InstructorDiff" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Instructors Difficulty</th>
      <th data-field="InstructorRating" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Instructors Rating</th>
      <th data-field="WouldTakeAgain" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Would Take Again</th>
      <th data-field="Comments" data-sortable="false" searchable="false">Comments</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  {% for course in courses %}
    <tr>
    <th scope="favorite_course">
    <form action="/favorite_courses/api/add_course/{{course.id}}" method="post">
        <button class="button is-success" name="foo" value="upvote">+</button>
    </form>
    </th>
    
    {% if instructors[course.instr]['image'] == None or instructors[course.instr]['image'] == "" %}
      <div class="image">
      </div>
    <td class="is-image-cell">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.yu.edu/sites/default/files/default_images/Placeholder_0.png" style="max-height:100px;width:100px;" class="is-rounded instr-profile">
      </div>
      </td>
    {% else %}
        <div class="image">
        </div>
      <td class="is-image-cell">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="{{instructors[course.instr]['image']}}" class="is-rounded instr-profile" style="max-height:100px;width:100px;">
        </div>
        </td>
    {% endif %}
      <td data-label="CRN">{{course.crn}}</td>
      <td data-label="Subject">{{course.subj}}</td>
      <td data-label="Course">{{course.crse}}</td>
      <td data-label="Credits">{{course.cred}}</td>
      <td class="instructor" data-label="Title">{{course.title}}</td>
      <td data-label="Days">{{course.days}}</td>
      <td data-label="Times">{{course.time}}</td>
      <td data-label="Instructor">{{course.instr}}</td>
      <td data-label="Attribute">{{course.attribute}}</td>
      
      <td width="30" data-width-unit="%" data-label="Instructors Difficulty">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <p class="bd-notification is-info"><center>{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}%</center></p>
          <div class="columns is-mobile">
            <div class="column">
              {% if instructors[course.instr]['profDiff'] | int >= 75 %}
              <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-danger" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}</progress></td>
              {% elif instructors[course.instr]['profDiff'] | int >= 50 %}
              <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-warning" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}</progress></td>
              {% else %}
              <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-primary" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}</progress></td>
              {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>

      <td data-label="Instructors Rating" class="is-progress-cell">
      <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="bd-notification is-info"><center>{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}%</center></p>
        <div class="columns is-mobile">
          <div class="column">
          {% if instructors[course.instr]['profRating'] | int >= 75 %}
          <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-primary" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}</progress></td>
          {% elif instructors[course.instr]['profRating'] | int>= 50 %}
          <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-warning" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}</progress></td>
          {% else %}
          <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-danger" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}</progress></td>
          {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      
      <td data-label="Would Take Again" class="is-progress-cell">
      <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="bd-notification is-info"><center>{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}%</center></p>
        <div class="columns is-mobile">
          <div class="column">
            {% if instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain'] | int >= 75 %}
            <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-primary" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</progress>
            {% elif instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain'] | int >= 50 %}
            <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-warning" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</progress>
            {% else %}
            <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-danger" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</progress>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
    <!-- {% include 'course_list/comments.html' %}  -->
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/themes/bulma/bootstrap-table-bulma.min.js"></script>
```

Video reference: https://streamable.com/grv9iy

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like this post :
[How to override bootstrap table td style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579473/how-to-override-bootstrap-table-td-style)

Or this one:
[How can I override Bootstrap CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721248/how-can-i-override-bootstrap-css-styles)

Sorry but without access to the code I can't help you any further. As I for an example don't have experience with bootstrap table. Only bootstrap, and bootstrap css is a pain to override.

But you can test these solutions and see if it works. Good luck

Comment: I added the code apologies! 

Also, those are for bootstrap style, but as mentioned I am using Bulma. I know the name for the library "bootstrap" throws it off but I am not using the "bootstrap" stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I know that you mentioned Bulma, but I tought those links would be at least relevant to your research. I will look further if I find anything. Css selectors didn't work?

Comment: If you haven't checked it already, look at this doc. Maybe it could help setting an scss file. https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/


Reading this github issue maybe could clarify something towards bulma.
https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2292