# can't set my css focus outline unless I use !important but this is discouraged...how do I troubleshoot this?

Tags: css

I know the reasons and the nuances for having outline there...I'm asking why this doesn't work:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

despite not having outline configured in any other css rules...yet when I use `!important`  it works fine....we're taught to avoid using !important as much as possible because it mucks up the [decreasing order of specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15582386/2226328).  Wonderful....so how do I walk through my code to figure out what causes this to happen?

Comment: Open the page in a browser and then look at the JavaScript/CSS console.  If another class be overriding this style,  then you will see it.

Comment: I did that before resorting to !important....crickets: http://puu.sh/oGAIF/c0b4667320.png ...I also tried searching by outline as well and it's as though the rule is not shown there...yet here it exists...in the source viewer on the inspector: http://puu.sh/oGAPb/c9d67bd862.png

Comment: Something else must be overriding the style.

Comment: I'm assuming bootstrap is causing the blue outline?

Answer (score 0):

If bootstrap is causing the blue outline, then this has worked for me in the past:

```
.form-control:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: yup I'm using bootstrap....but wouldn't using the wildcard `*` already supercede `.form-control` class?